# how to extend specific method in a child class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

i m not very good with oop but know little bit of it.

Well i am trying to extend a class.. actually i want to add some additional functionality to class method...

This is the class, I am trying to extend

> https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/metaboxes/meta_box.php

with the following code in `save_box()` method

```
if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && 'testimonials' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'testimonials_save_post' );

    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => 'Testimonial - ' . $post_id
    ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'testimonials_save_post' );
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? To execute your code and then the method `save_box()` in `meta_box.php`?

Comment: the above class "Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes" is working fine, but in my Custom Post type i didn't support for 'title', so when i save and see the list of items in Testimonials section it show the "no title" so i want to add some code for testimonials posttype. that when i save without title i will show like "testimonial - 1100" so can add the above code in save_box method

Comment: the above code is taken from " http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-client-testimonials-with-custom-post-types--wp-30263 "

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of instantiating the child class which contains only the new method. Considering the [sample file](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/inc/sample.php):

```
include_once( 'meta_box.php' ); // ORIGINAL
include_once('my-class.php');   // CHILD

// Instantiate the Child Class
$sample_box = new My_Custom_Add_Meta_Box( 'sample_box', 'Sample Box', $fields, 'post', true );
```

And `my-class.php` would contain:

```
class My_Custom_Add_Meta_Box extends Custom_Add_Meta_Box {
    /**
     * saves the captured data
     */
    function save_box( $post_id ) {
        wp_die('Child class save method called.');
        # do_something();
    }
}
```